# Why are the duplicates in my lists not merging even with set?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

An example of the problem looks like this:

```
[{'00016F745862898F': ['2963419753', '5737807753', '2963419753', '5737807753', '', ''],
  '00157F1570C74E09': ['2362603155', '7053812209', '', '', '', '7053812209']}
```

I would like the numbers that are the same to merge together. I am trying to create another dictionary from this one but whenever I try set or union but I still get the same result. The reason I am using set is because the values come from merging the list together. I'm trying to incorporate it into my code that removes the `''` as well.

I can show the whole code if it is confusing.

Code that I tried already:

```
for k, v in full.items():
    tmp = []
    for i in v:
        if i != '':
            tmp.append(i)
    list(set().union(tmp))
    out[k] = tmp
    print(tmp)
```

and

```
for k, v in full.items():
    tmp = []
    for i in v:
        if i != '':
            tmp.append(i)
    out[k] = set(tmp)
    print(tmp)
```

Those still give me the same output as above.

The desired output would be below, where the elements that are the same will merge:

```
[{'00016F745862898F': ['2963419753', '5737807753',],
  '00157F1570C74E09': ['2362603155', '7053812209',]}
```

Comment: Can you fix the trailing braces? } and ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first example

```
list(set().union(tmp))
```

This creates a new set and a new list, while **keeping `tmp` intact**. You'll have to save this deduplicated new list and use it afterwards.

In your second example

```
out[k] = set(tmp)
print(tmp)
```

You saved the new set, but you're still *printing* the old one. You should have used `print(out[k])` or similar.

Comment: thats where I was going wrong! I just changed what it was iterating

Answer (score 2):

Simply this?

```
old = {'00016F745862898F': ['2963419753', '5737807753', '2963419753', '5737807753', '', ''],'00157F1570C74E09': ['2362603155', '7053812209', '', '', '', '7053812209']}

new = {key: list(set(val)-{''}) for key, val in old.items()}
```

Comment: great use of set operations :)